# Adding a view that displays user data using store Sencha touch2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, store, sencha-touch-2.1

My store JSON looks like this:

```
"content" : {
    "RecId" : "123",
    "CustNo" : "123",
    "Attn" : "",
    "AcctManagFirst": "Sample ",
    "AcctManagLast": "Sample2",
    "Name": "Works",
    "Terms": "1234",
    "Freight":0,
    "Taxable":1,
    "TaxTable": "EXEMPT",
    "TaxTableRate": "0.000000",
    "BillToAddr": "GGGGGGGGG",
    "BCity": "New Iberia",
    "BState": "LA",
    "BZip": "70560",
    "WHAddr": "Perry",
    "WHCity": "New Iberia",
    "WHState": "LA",
    "WHZip": "70560"
}
```

Using the above I want create a view that displays user information like:

```
Name                              {Name from the store}
AccountManager Last NAme            {AcctManagLast from the store}
```

I am new to Sencha . Plese help me how to write form that displays the label followed by value from store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple panel with template and data will work for you, check out : http://www.senchafiddle.com/#KmNX8#yqVQt

Comment: I added my view here... but I the panel is not working for me...thank you for the answer .. can you please tell me how to add that to the view under the title bar items  http://www.senchafiddle.com/#OoFEs

Comment: panel can me item#2 in items array if item#1 is titlebar

Comment: excellent..got it.... trying to add different item arrays... now added in one array ...working... Thank you

Comment: I have one more question ... my tab bar bottom is not showing on all views... like I will go to the following view on button tap ..there the tab bar is not showing...this is my onbuttontap function myAccFunction: function() { // MY ACCOUNT VIEW FUNCTION
            var MyUser=  Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Sample.view.Userinfo'));
            Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(MyUser, this.getSlideLeftTransition());
       console.log('UserinfoAction');
          },
tab bar is showing when I go directly to the view using tab icon.. but when I go using button tab bar is not showing ..

Comment: You should probably accept answer for the original question and post this issue as separate question, mixing different questions in one is not a good idea

Comment: I have a problem with the same question..Here the data in the view is static but my store data changes from user to user .. then how to retrieve dynamic data,I tried to add data in the store but it is really confusing and raising errors